# GCP: gcoud ai-platform jobs list --project my-project-id fails to list projects, when Vertex AI UI shows models are training

Tags: python, github, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Google Vertex AI job appears to be running in UI, after starting job from UI, but "gcloud ai-platform jobs list --project my-project-id" command shows "Listed 0 items."

Steps I followed:

1. Upload my dataset from .csv file.
2. I select the "train new model" button in datasets UI.

[image]

3. I select "other"

[image]

4. I fill in all my training information for the tabular regression task.
5. I select "train model", and my model begins to train.

At this point I want to be able list my currently running jobs, from the command line, so I try these commands in the GCP cloud terminal:

I have tried running all these commands and got the following outputs. :

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs list --project my-project-id
output: Listed 0 items.
gcloud alpha ai-platform jobs list --project my-project-id
output: Listed 0 items.
gcloud beta ai-platform jobs list --project my-project-id
output: Listed 0 items.
gcloud ai-platform jobs list --billing-project project my-project-id
output: Listed 0 items.
```

However, as you can see below, the model appears to be training, but when I try to view my active training jobs, using the commands listed above, I get back "Listed 0 items."

Furthermore,
[image]

My ultimate goal of using this command is to add it to a github action workflow, that will continue to run while the running jobs "Listed items" > 0, and ends the workflow when the Listed items = 0.

Comment: Could you try this `gcloud ai custom-jobs list ` [cli command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/list). Let me know if this helps you or not?

Comment: @kiranmathew That did return a list of the jobs I tried; however, it only shows the jobs that succeeded, and those that failed, it is not showing the jobs that are in training, which is what I am most interested in. Furthermore it shows 3 jobs succeeded when I only ran one model, which is something I am unsure about as well. 

So I tried starting up another training job.

I tried this command to see if it would list jobs that are "training":
gcloud ai custom-jobs list --project=my-project-id --region=us-central1 --filter="state!=JOB_STATE_SUCCEEDED", did not return any training job.

Comment: @JohnHanley I used this command to list my permissions: 

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy my-project-id\
  --flatten="bindings[].members" \
  --format="table(bindings.role)" \
  --filter="bindings.members:my-email"
```

Here is the output: 
```
ROLE: roles/billing.projectManager

ROLE: roles/owner

ROLE: roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin
```

Comment: The IAM role `owner` has the required permissions (229 `aiplatform` permissions).